# If we have a group map $f:G \to H$, how do we get the induced map $\bar{f}: G/G' \to H/H'$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

To make myself clear, I want to know what guarantees that such a well defined map exists, and that it is induced by $f$?

I was reading this somewhere and all that was checked to ensure the map exists and was well defined was that $f(G') \subset H'$.

Before seeing this, I though there was some universal property that guaranteed such a map, using the natural epimorphisms $\pi_1:G \to G/N$ and $\pi_2:H \to H/K$, where $N, K$ are normal in $G, H$, respectively, but maybe there is no such universal property?

Can someone please explain precisely what is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The map you want is the map that sends $g G'$ to $f(g)  H'$.  It's clear that this gives a homomorphism provided that it's even well-defined, so just examine when the thing I wrote actually means something.  In particular, if two elements of $G$ differ by an element of $G'$ then we need to send them to the same place, which is the same as saying that we need to send elements of $g'$ to the identity in $H/H'$.  So what we need is precisely that $f(G') \subseteq H'$.

If you want to use more "algebraic" techniques, note that you can compose $f$ with the projection $H \to H/H'$, giving a map
$$G \xrightarrow{f} H \xrightarrow{\pi} H/H'$$
Now:

- If $f(G') \subset H'$ then $G'$ is in the kernel of $(\pi \circ f)$, so $(\pi \circ f)$ induces a map $G/G' \to H/H'$.
- If not, then it isn't, so it doesn't.

Comment: Thanks so much. Can you please explain exactly what is meant by "if two elements of $G$ differ by an element of $G'$′′, I don't think I get what you mean there. That rest is clear.

Comment: Well, we wrote what happens to an element of $G/G'$ in terms of a representative $g \in G$.  We need to make sure this doesn't depend on the choice of representative.  So if we have two representatives for the same element of $G/G'$, say $g_1$ and $g_2$, then $g_1 G' = g_2 G'$.  That's the same as saying $g_2^{-1} g_1 G' = G'$, which is the same as saying that $g_2^{-1} g_1 \in G'$.  In other words, the difference between $g_1$ and $g_2$ is an element of $G'$.